# Prove that is a topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Let X be any set having more that one element . Pick $ a \in X $ , then fix it. The one-point topology on X is $τ_a $ = {∅,X, {a}} Check that $ τ_a $ is indeed a topology on X

Comment: what part of this question are you finding difficult?

Comment: What have you tried. You are asked to verify that $\tau_a$ is indeed a topology, i.e. to check whether it satisfies the conditions that are  characteristic for a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology#Topologies_on_sets).

Comment: @dbx Do you use the conditions of topology or what?

Comment: @user510071 Is $\tau_a$ closed under arbitrary unions? That's one thing. Also check the others.

Comment: someone more charitable than I has gone and done the work for you below.

Comment: @dbx Well thank him , why you talk this way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to prove that it satisfies the axioms of a topology, that are :

1) $\emptyset$, $X$ are open sets.

2) Any union of open sets is an open set.

3) Any finite intersection of open sets is an open set.

Here, you indeed have $\emptyset, X \in \tau_a$, so $1)$ is ok.

Then, all the possible unions $\emptyset \cup \lbrace a \rbrace = \lbrace a \rbrace$, $\emptyset \cup X = X$ and $X \cup \lbrace a \rbrace = X$ are in $\tau_a$ so $2)$ is ok.

And finally, all the possible intersections $\emptyset \cap \lbrace a \rbrace = \emptyset$, $\emptyset \cap X = \emptyset$ and $X \cap \lbrace a \rbrace = \lbrace a \rbrace$ are in $\tau_a$ so $3)$ is ok.